# What caused Uncaught Runtime Error: Object Event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got this error

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
[object Event]
    at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_webpack-dev-server_client_index_js_protocol_ws_3A_hostname_0_0_0_0_port_-848880.807f658b.js:2551:58)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_webpack-dev-server_client_index_js_protocol_ws_3A_hostname_0_0_0_0_port_-848880.807f658b.js:2570:7
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:266:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:321:31)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:23232:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:22186:12)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:22159:22)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:21785:9)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:11118:24
    at unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.2b6f5974.chunk.js:26106:12)
```

when trying to run react in local.

What I've done:

- clear cache
- delete node_modules and npm install

does anyone know why this error happened? got no idea as the error code is very short. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Along with node_modules kindly also delete the package-lock.json file and yarn.lock file(if present) and then do npm install.